# Why the layer must be created from my class and not from layer class

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am confused about something. 
I have the following example:

**mainMenu.h**

```
class mainMenu : public Node {
public:
    static Scene* createScene();
    virtual bool init();
    void GoToGameScene(Ref *pSender);
    CREATE_FUNC(mainMenu);


private:
    mainMenu() {};
    ~mainMenu() {};


};
```

**mainMenu.cpp**

```
Scene* mainScene::createScene(){
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = mainScene::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);

    return scene;
}
```

Focus on this part.

```
auto scene = Scene::create();
auto layer = mainScene::create();
```

Why do we create layer from `mainScene` not from `Layer`

For example: Why we do this:

```
auto layer = mainScene::create();
```

If we can do it, like creating a scene

```
auto layer = Layer::create();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's very uncommon to start classnames with a lowercase letter. It makes the code harder to understand.

Second, I'm not sure if I got your question right, but it seems like you're asking:
**Why call a `create()` method on the `mainScene` class instead of just using a simple `Layer::create()`?**

If that's the case then the answer is quite simply: Because in this way we can customize how the `mainScene` should be initialized. Perhaps it needs several layers, like a HUD layer, a game layer, a controls layer, etc. By calling its `create()` method we make sure the constructor of `mainScene` is called, but also it's created as a `Ref` object, meaning that it'll be reference counted and therefore the memory management will be done automagically (for the most part).

If that wasn't the question feel free to explain it to me a bit further.

Comment: C++ Has no common conventions. He can write however he wants. This is also the main reason why C++ is such a terrible language.